# Have 3prong dryer cord and 4prong dryer outlet.how do i chane it to work how much and show me pics n videos

Tags: receptacle, dryer

How to change 3prong to 4 prong dryer cord
How to wire a 3prong outlet where a 4 prong is currently?

Comment: In pretty much any dryer made in the last 30+ years, it is very easy to make the switch. **Keep the 4-prong outlet as is, do not change it.** Typically with the model # you can find directions, but basically: *Take off back panel, unscrew old cord. Screw in new cord, including ground wire, **remove** wire connecting neutral and ground on the dryer, put back panel back on.*

Comment: What make and model is your dryer?

Comment: *"How to wire a 3prong outlet where a 4 prong is currently?"* Don't. That's a code violation. Use a 4-prong cord, and change the wiring on the dryer to suit it (there are usually instructions on the dryer itself - if not, look up the manual for the dryer.)

Comment: 3 wire 240v dryer or range receptacles are only legal where the existing circuit is missing the 4th (ground) wire. The existence of a 4 wire receptacle is evidence a ground exists, so you need to change the dryer to match the receptacle. The instructions for your brand of dryer can be found online to install a 4 wire cord.